# How can I run docker image using singularity?

Tags: docker, singularity-container

I would like to run a docker image with singularity (I have never used either).

The person who made the docker image suggested to locate the terminal shell to the location where the files (that are used as input for the docker image) are located and then do:

`docker run -v ${PWD}:/DATA -w /DATA -i image/myimage -specifications`

I am able to run this image using singularity when I omit `${PWD}:/DATA -w /DATA` and indicate the paths to input files and docker image. But I would prefer to run it as in the example above. Can someone tell me how I can do this using singularity? I saw that `singularity run --bind` might be a way, but couldn’t figure out how. I know this is very basic, but I’m just starting to learn this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With Docker, `-v ${PWD}:/DATA -w /DATA` will mount the current directory inside the container to the specified location (`/Data`). 
You can easily emulate this behaviour with Singularity if you use `--bind` instead of `-v`:

```
--bind ${PWD}:/DATA -w /DATA
```

However, the Docker WORKDIR (`-w/--workdir`) is not the same as the Singularity option `-W/--workdir`. Depending on what you want to do exactly, `singularity exec --pwd` might be able to replace Dockers `-w` argument.